# After adding data in firebase database my html table not update in realtime

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a JavaScript project where I create a html table and show table data from firebase database that is working fine, my problem is that when I add a data in my firebase database through html page it successfully stored in firebase database but my html table not update in realtime, it show after refresh the page, below I add my js code

```
database.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
    if (snapshot.exists()){
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        var row = tblUsers.insertRow(rowIndex);
        var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
        var cellButtons = row.insertCell(1).outerHTML =
            "<tr id='row" + rowIndex + "'><td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"delete_row('" + childKey + "')\"></td></tr>";

        cellName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.desc));
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
        document.getElementById("empty_data").style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
    } else{
        document.getElementById("empty_data").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
});
```

Anyone help to solve the problem

Comment: Please have a look at the edit I just made to your question, as before that edit your question did not show the most important line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a listener with `once()` is reads the value once (as its name implies) and then stops listening for changes. If you want to continue to listen for changes, use `on()` instead.

That also means that you can't use `then()` anymore, as `on()` can result in getting data multiple times, so it doesn't return a promise (which can be called only once).

So the change should be limited to the first line of the code you shared and look like this:

```
database.on("value", function(snapshot){
  ...
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I already tried and it works but problem is that it add same value with multiple time :(

Comment: yes are right, i am also thinking that but I am not figure out how to clear the table data?

Comment: That depends on your HTML, which unfortunately I couldn't figure out from the code you posted. Someting like `tblUsers.clear()` or `tblUsers.innerHTML = ""` might be it. But searching for "how to clear the dynamic rows from my HTML table" should give you good answers for that question, while my answer focused on the question you posted here: how do I get realtime data updates from Firebase.